# How to modify global variable (type: array) in handler function

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an array in the following format:

agendaItems = [{"topic":"blah", "description:"blah"}, {"topic":"blah2", "description":"blah2"}].

I need to update the values in this array in a handler and handler does not allow global variables to be modified.  I know I have to use either CacheService or ScriptProperties.  However, I can't seem to make it work:

If I use CacheService, I get something like this: "[object oject][object object]"

```
CacheService.getPublicCache.put('agenda', agendaItems);
```

If I use ScriptProperties, I get something like this: ""[Ljava.lang.Object;@429bd3a7"

```
ScriptProperties.setProperty('agenda', agendaItems');
```

Am I doing this wrong or is there a better way?  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_cache) class works with strings. You have to use the [Utilities.jsonStringify](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities#jsonStringify) and [Utilities.jsonParse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities#jsonParse) methods to convert the array to a string and vice versa. Here is slightly modified code which I use

```
this.getData = function(id, cacheKey) {
  var cache = CacheService.getPrivateCache();
  var cachedString = cache.get(cacheKey);
  var lstData;
  if (cachedString == null) {
    lstData = getNotCachedData_(id);
    cache.put(cacheKey, Utilities.jsonStringify(lstData));
  }
  else {
    lstData = Utilities.jsonParse(cachedString);
  }
  return lstData;
}
```

The [ScriptProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_scriptproperties) Service also works with strings. It is not obvious due to the [not complete documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_scriptproperties#setProperty), the `value` parameter has type `var` and not `String`, but it is true.

Comment: Thanks, using json is giving me the correct data. However, I'm getting an error "Error Encountered: Invalid Argument" after I added the json code to a handler function and I have no clue what is causing this.  I copied the code to a non-handler function and there is no error.

Comment: @mdho, I answered to your [next question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168862/error-encountered-invalid-argument-in-handler-function).