# "Error Encountered: Invalid Argument" in handler function

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm getting this error in my handler function but I've no clue what's causing it.  I've copied the code and debugged it in a non-handler function and there was no error.

```
function _responseToNext(e) {

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('btnPrev').setEnabled(true);

  var current = parseInt(CacheService.getPublicCache().get('currentItem')); 
  var agendaItems = Utilities.jsonParse(CacheService.getPublicCache().get('agenda'));

  agendaItems[current]['notes'] = e.parameter.tAreaNotes;
  agendaItems[current]['status'] = e.parameter.lboxStatus;

  CacheService.getPublicCache().put('agenda', Utilities.jsonStringify(agendaItems));

  current = current + 1;
  CacheService.getPublicCache().put('currentItem', current); 

  fillAgendaDetail(app);

  // only enabled 'Next' if there are more items in the agenda
  if (current < agendaItems.length-1) { 
  app.getElementById('btnNext').setEnabled(true); 
  }

  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, the error cause is that the Cache `get` method returns null during the 1st execution when the cache is empty. The `Utilities.jsonParse` throws an exception and the cache becomes in any case empty. Try to use the following modified code.

```
function _responseToNext(e) {

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('btnPrev').setEnabled(true);

  var cachedCurrent = CacheService.getPublicCache().get('currentItem');
  var current;
  if (cachedCurrent == null) {
    current = 0;
  }
  else {
    current = parseInt(cachedCurrent); 
  }
  var cachedAgendaItems = CacheService.getPublicCache().get('agenda');
  var agendaItems;
  if (cachedAgendaItems == null) {
    agendaItems = [][];
  }
  else {
    agendaItems = Utilities.jsonParse();
  }

  agendaItems[current]['notes'] = e.parameter.tAreaNotes;
  agendaItems[current]['status'] = e.parameter.lboxStatus;

  CacheService.getPublicCache().put('agenda', Utilities.jsonStringify(agendaItems));

  current = current + 1;
  CacheService.getPublicCache().put('currentItem', current); 

  fillAgendaDetail(app);

  // only enabled 'Next' if there are more items in the agenda
  if (current < agendaItems.length-1) { 
  app.getElementById('btnNext').setEnabled(true); 
  }

  return app;
}
```

Also please mention that the Public Cache (`CacheService.getPublicCache()`) is the same for all users of your script. In your case, this means, if two users `user1@example.com` and `user2@example.com` use the script they will have the same `current` and `agendaItems` variables values, i.e. it can be a situation when the `_responseToNext` handler is already executed under the `user1` authority - the `current` variable is equal to 1, after the user2 executes the `_responseToNext` handler - the `current` variable is equal to 2 and so on. If you do not need such behaviour, use the `CacheService.getPrivateCache()`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the actual cause since I assign a value to cache at the beginning of the calling function.  However, I'm no longer seeing the error, so Thanks!